# App ending on rotation and timer not being saved

Tags: java, android-studio

So I'm having two issues with the below code which I'm looking for guidance on, when rotating the device the app works for one question then ends and takes the user to the results page, I can't for the life of me see why it would end if the answer is correct??

Second I have been unable to save the countdown timer when rotating the device, it resets back to 59 secs (i've deleted the code used as it clearly wasn't working) however I was using putInt("time", times);

Any thoughts? TIA

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuestionActivity extends Activity {

List<Question> quesList;
int score = 0;
int qid = 0;

Question currentQ;
TextView txtQuestion, times, scored;
Button button1, button2, button3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    QuizHelper db = new QuizHelper(this);  // question class
    quesList = db.getAllQuestions();  // returns all questions
    currentQ = quesList.get(qid); // current question by id

    txtQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion); //displays the current question

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); //button 1 displays option 1 for answer
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); //button 2 displays option 2 for answer
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3); //button 3 displays option 3 for answer

    scored = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score); //Displays the score

    times = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers); //displays the timer

    setQuestionView();

    CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(60000, 1000); //countdown timer set to 1 minute
    CountDownTimer start = timer.start();//starts the timer

    //listeners
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getAnswer(button1.getText().toString()); //checks if answer is correct
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getAnswer(button2.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getAnswer(button3.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}

public void getAnswer(String AnswerString) {
    if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(AnswerString)) {
        score++; //increments the score by 1 if correct
        scored.setText("Score : " + score); //updates the score display
    }

    else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, ResultActivity.class); //if incorrect ends the game

        Bundle b = new Bundle(); //passes the score
        b.putInt("score", score); // The end score
        intent.putExtras(b); // displays the score on the closing screen
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    if (qid != 21) { //if question id not equal to 21 get next question and update current question
        currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
        setQuestionView();
    }
}

public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {

    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

   @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        times.setText("Time is up");
        onFinish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
        String timerlayout = String.format("%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) % 60, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) % 60); //sets the layout of the timer
        System.out.println(timerlayout);
        times.setText(timerlayout);
    }
}

private void setQuestionView() { //creates the overall question and options for answer
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
    button1.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
    button2.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
    button3.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
    qid++; //increments the question id by 1
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outSate) {
    outSate.putString("myQu", txtQuestion.getText().toString());
    outSate.putString("1", button1.getText().toString());
    outSate.putString("2", button2.getText().toString());
    outSate.putString("3", button3.getText().toString());

    outSate.putString("score", scored.getText().toString());


    super.onSaveInstanceState(outSate);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceSate) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceSate);

    txtQuestion.setText( savedInstanceSate.getString("myQu"));
    button1.setText( savedInstanceSate.getString("1"));
    button2.setText( savedInstanceSate.getString("2"));
    button3.setText( savedInstanceSate.getString("3"));

    scored.setText( savedInstanceSate.getString("score"));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorted, the issue was due to the timer. The existing on the question is still an issue but I have an idea for it and will ask again if needed.